# Selecting last record in SQL Server database not always working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

There is claims table which when a user creates a claim, it then gets inserted into this table, each claim is supposed to have its own unique `NaturalOrderID` allocated to it, the `NaturalOrderID` is generated by the system, here is the first part of the code, this method gets the maximum number which is the last number to be used later to come with a new unique `NaturalOrderID`

```
 private int GetLastNaturalClaimNo(string finYear)
 {
        int maxNo = 0;
        string query = string.Empty;

        query = @"SELECT MAX(CAST(SubString(NaturalOrderId, 4,50) AS int)) FROM Claim
WHERE NaturalOrderId LIKE '" + finYear + "/%' AND (CAST(SubString(NaturalOrderId, 4,50) AS int) BETWEEN 10000 AND 500000) ";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RAC_DARAConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);// ***OLD Query**
            conn.Open();

            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            // If no claim of this sort is found, then we are starting a new financial year.
            maxNo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString()) ? 10000 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }

        return maxNo;
    }
```

Then this return maxim will be used to allocated the new `NaturalOrderId` to the new claim that will be created, here is the code that generates a new `OrderId` based on the maximum number from the previous method

```
public string GenerateNaturalClaimNumber(int claimId, DateTime date, string userName)
{
        // Get the financial period
        string finYear = GetFinancialYear(date);

        // Get the maximum claim inserted
        int maxClaimNo = GetLastNaturalClaimNo(finYear);

        int newClaimNo = maxClaimNo + 1;

        string naturalNo = finYear + "/" + newClaimNo.ToString();

        // Update the claim with the new number ASAP (before someone else grabs the number and creates a duplicate)
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RAC_DARAConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = @"UPDATE Claim SET 
                    NaturalOrderId = @naturalNo, 
                    UserName = @userName
                    WHERE ClaimId = @claimId";
            //"UPDATE Claim SET NaturalOrderId = '" + naturalNo + "' WHERE ClaimId = " + claimId.ToString()
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naturalNo", naturalNo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) ? null : userName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClaimId", claimId.ToString()); // it was claimNo
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return naturalNo;
    }
```

My problem is, this doesn't always seem to work as it sometimes allocate same `naturalOrderId` to two or more different claims (screen shot of few examples attached)

[NaturalOrderID duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MMD6.png)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure each claim has its own unique NaturalOrderID? This issue seems more to do with how the table is set up than with the C# code.

Comment: *NaturalOrder is generated by the system* - When does it do so? You are getting same `NaturalOrderId` because there is no `NaturalOrder` created during subsequent claims.

Comment: This is a very typical example of concurrency gone awry. You are experiencing multiple claims being entered at the same time and the MAX is not always what you think due to the race conditions. Use an identity instead, it handles all this stuff with no effort on your part.

Comment: As others have pointed out you should use Sql Server Identity column so the database will create the value in that column. Also you should constrain your data whenever possible in your database. In this case you could also create an `UNIQUE INDEX` on column `NaturalOrderId`, this will ensure that a duplicate will never be permitted on that column.

Comment: By saying each has it own unique NaturalOrderId I was just clarifying my question, perhaps the best word should have been "each claim must have its own unique naturalOrderId"  @Igor very good idea,unique index should indeed solve my issue because I have an identity column already so this NaturalOrderId that is generated and will be used on another system hence its a must for it to be on the database. Thank you so much everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are computing the `naturalOrderID` at your appside, you 100% should be using the `identity` column that SQL Server provides. What is probably happening is you have multiple orders going in at the same time, so when you pull that max ID someone else is inserting while you are calculating. Thus your natural order is out of sync.

Try and use the [SQL Server Identity property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Problem arises from the fact that there is small time gap between querying next available number for NaturalOrderId and persisting record. If two records are created at roughly the same time, you will run into conflict as both of them will have the same NaturalOrderId.

You should translate that responsibility of NaturalOrderId generation to database.

Easiest way to do this would be to define Identity column:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

If all you care is right order of records, another option is sequential Guid: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

Please note that sequential Guid can re-start from lower range if hosting system is shut down.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, you 100% correct the problem here comes when two claims are created at the same time, I am thinking of introducing a unique constraint on the NaturalOrderID since I already have an identity column(ClaimId), you reckon this should be a good fix?

Comment: It depends, but in general introducing constraint won't be enough. You will still generate two identical NaturalOrderId values, the difference will be that you will get an exception when trying to persist the second one. Of course, you can try to re-calculate it if there is an exception and try to store it again. Depending on how often records are inserted this might be viable solution. Mind that it would not guarantee that record would be persisted in reasonable time because NaturalOrderId conflicts might occur again and again for the same record.